# Allow local users to access /var/www folder in vsftpd

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, vsftpd

I have successfully installed the vsftpd. and it is live, but I get following error:

```
Response:   500 OOPS: cannot change directory:/home/sovit
```

What I want to do is direct all local users of the system to the `/var/www` folder instead of their home root.

Below is the vsftpd conf file:

http://pastie.org/2284176

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out there was no directory created for user in home directory. I created it and set the local root to /var/www and it worked

Answer (score 0):

- Define an unprivileged user with `nopriv_user`, assuming is
  `ftpsecure`
- Change GID of all the ftp users to the same with `ftpsecure`
- Change the `umask` of webserver user and vsftpd to 002
- `chmod -R g+w /var/www`

PS: As another way: you can change the $HOME folder of ftp user to the /var/www instead of setting `local_root` in `vsftpd.conf`.

Comment: let me try this